# How to list the items of a sortable grid-list in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently playing with the **sortable** interactions in jQuery. As for now, I added an unsorted list which is being displayed as a grid to my project. The *source code* is equivalent to the one I found in the [jQuery demo section](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid). I want the users to be able to display some values of a database, let them move each item to a position of their choice and send the changes back to the server. I implemented pretty much everything to do so, I however don't know how to obtain a list of the items on the client side, after users sorted the list according to their needs.

My question is: How can I get an array of all items after the user has moved the items around? I attempted to access the list's source code using something like this:

```
$( "#sortable" ).toArray()[0]
```

Which returns a **HTMLUListElement** object. The field *innerText* is undefined and *innerHTML* returns the source code of the entire unsorted list, I however would like to iterate through all the items of this list.

There has to be an easier way to access them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#sortable li')
```

returns all the elements in your sortable.
If you want to display the values of them you can use

```
$('#sortable li').text()
```

which will print out all the text values of all the nodes in the right(sorted) order.

To access each of them separately you can use

```
$('#sortable li').eq(index)
```

or

```
$('#sortable li')[index]
```

Comment: I am happy that helped, beta!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is what you need:

```
$("#sortable").sortable( "toArray" )[0]
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

$(#sortable) gets you the tag that is sortable, .sortable gets you access to the sortable methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well, lukas.pukenis was slightly faster, though. +1 anyways. ;)